# CSS Transition Not Updating Background Color on Increased Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So very simple. I have a page with a white background. When I click a button, a div displays showing content and the background behind the div dims. I have the dim on a 2 second transition for cinema like effect.
The dim works fine when the information in the div does not exceed the browser's established height. However, if the div box increases the browsers height, any part of the new height that is currently displayed to the user, while the transition is going on, does not dim (IE it stays white). If a part of the new height is below the browser window during the effect and if you scroll down it stops that part of the windows transition. Otherwise if the new portion of the height is not seen during the transition, it dims all the way.
Seems like it can't draw the background change while being seen, which seems silly.
Here's my code:

**CSS** #body-back is the id for the body tag

```
#body-back {
  -webkit-transition: background 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: background 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: background 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: background 2s ease-in-out;
}
```

**JS**

```
<script>
pop = function() {
  var back = document.getElementById('body-back');
  back.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.8)";
}
popaway = function() {
  var back = document.getElementById('body-back');
  back.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0)";
}

#Show the div box            
$( "#button" ).click(function( e ) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $("#divbox").toggle();
  pop();
});

$( "#divbox" ).on('click',function( e ) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

#Hide the div box if user clicks outside of div box
$( document ).on('click', function( e ) {
  if( e.target.id != 'divbox' ){
    $( "#divbox" ).hide();
    popaway();
  }   
});
</script>
```

Also for note, when I don't have the background on transition and just a basic switch, it renders perfectly, even on any new browser height space.
Any ideas as to why it doesn't want to draw on exposed new space? Thanks guys!

**Edit**
I have been running it in Chrome, but just tried in Safari. For Safari, even if the new height is off screen, it still does not draw the updated background.

**Edit 2 - Div Box CSS**

```
.popup {
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  margin-left:100px;
  margin-right:100px;
  width:85%;
  font-family:verdana;
  font-size:13px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color:white;
  border:2px solid grey;
  z-index:100000000000000000;
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: I think you will have to post the css for #divbox and #body-back, if you can make a http://jsfiddle.net/, people will be able to solve it for you more easily

Comment: Where you relying on #divbox's margin-bottom to expand the parent element? if so, it won't work http://jsfiddle.net/2dxnp/8/

Comment: try putting overflow:auto on #body-back !

Comment: I did some updating on the fiddle with the overflow but also setting the height to 100%. The difference that I see is that the inside box is still inline with the outside box, where as mine is an absolute position. I'll edit the question with the css of the div box

Comment: oh yea absolute position, so it won't affect the size of the parent element at all. one fix might be to add top: 50px, position:fixed to the .popup ,this will make it ignore scrolling on the body completely. and then set a min-height on the body as you did

Comment: Ahhhhh you are brilliant! Final was top: 50px; position:fixed;overflow:scroll;width:70%; Put it up as an answer, because it looks amazing! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: awesome! glad we got there in the end lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

position: absolute will not affect the height of the parent element. Position fixed will make it overlayyed on top, ignoring the scrolling of the page entirely.

sounds like this worked for you

```
.popup {
   top: 50px; 
   position:fixed; /* sit on top of everything, ignore scrolling on the body*/
   overflow:scroll;
   width:70%;
}
```

by default the body should take up 100% height, not sure why that was not happening for you before.

Glad it worked and that i could help in the end!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this does not address the issue here, ( but putting styles in CSS is generaly a good thing :)

Try animating background-color

This question [explains animating background opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254943/how-can-i-animate-the-opacity-of-the-background-of-a-div-in-jquery). It's usually easier to put all of the styles in CSS rather than JavaScript. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565587/css-transition-opacity-on-mouse-out)

```
 .pop{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
 }

 #body-back {
    //polyfills..
    transition: background-color 2s  ease-in-out;

   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
 }
```

javascript

```
pop = function() {
   $('#body-back').addClass('pop');
}
popaway  = function() {
   $('#body-back').removeClass('pop');
}
```

Comment: You said to animate background-color but on transition: you have it pointing to opacity. When I do opacity, there is no transition, even if I change the value in .pop to opacity. Otherwise if I change the transition: opactity to transition: background-color I get a transition, but the same issue as before.

Comment: oops, my bad, that should be background color, not opacity there!

Comment: Gotcha, well I'm still getting the no rendering of the background issue even with background-color instead of background like I had it.
Also I realized I was doing the opacity wrong and that is working now, but I really want background color because I like the dark effect is has. You understand what I meant about the new height and not drawing issue right?

Comment: ahh just re-read your question, I missed the point at first, your issue is actually more interesting

Comment: Ya its a pain, been workin on it for too long now and I've thrown everything I can think of at it.
Here's a screenshot of what the html debugger shows me when the div box pushes the bottom down past its original bottom. The blue is Chrome, not the dim. That is dimmed under the blue. The white, obviously outside of the div box (thats holding the pictures) is the new space on the bottom that isn't transitioning, or like I said before, if the screen isn't able to see it, it will transition.
http://postimg.org/image/dkg993gxr/

Comment: try this: #body-back{ overflow:auto;}