# Anime.js backgroundColor giving unexpected results

Tags: javascript, css, animation

So I've been playing around with Anime.js. I'm using this short bit of code to try and animate a `div` tag with a single letter id of `a`.

```
anime({
    targets: "#a",
    translateX: 250,
    color: "#fff",
    backgroundColor: "hsl(200, 50%, 50%)",
    loop: true,
    direction: 'alternate',
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
});
```

The problem is that (at least for me in Google Chrome) the element seems to start out at the beginning of the animation with a css `background-color` of black, even though it doesn't have any background color specifically set in the css. A bit of digging seems to suggest that the default background color of the element is rgba(0,0,0,0) and that Anime.js doesn't seem to work when using colors with alpha channels. I think this explains why the animation starts with black. Setting a background color for the element in the css seems to solve the issue, even if it has an alpha channel, but the alpha channel is never honored in the animation.

But what if I want to animate from a background color of `rgba(0,0,0,0)` to a solid color? A Google search does not reveal much information since Anime.js is fairly new. Does anybody know of any way that I can make this work in Anime.js? If Anime.js doesn't support this functionality, does anyone know of another JavaScript animation library that does? I need support for animating colors with alpha channels.

For convenience, here's a demo of what I've slapped together so far
[in a quick CodePen.](https://codepen.io/aaronbeaudoin/pen/BZaPve)

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but I am  currently playing with anime.js and found your question. You can define a start value for the background animation.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  anime({
    targets: ".box",
    translateX: 250,
    color: "#fff",
    backgroundColor: ["hsl(250, 75%, 50%)", "hsl(200, 50%, 50%)"],
    loop: true,
    direction: 'alternate',
    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@2.2.4" data-semver="2.2.4" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.2.0/anime.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Anime.js animate Background Color</h1>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me whether anime.js supports opacity. You can however user JQuery animate, with JQuery UI installed.

```
$('#a').animate({ 'background-color': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)' },1000);
```

You can see the complete answer in [How can I animate the opacity of the background of the div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16254943/how-can-i-animate-the-opacity-of-the-background-of-a-div)

Comment: The link doesn't work for me. Also do you know of a library with better performance than jQuery with this functionality?

Comment: @AaronBeaudoin Fixed the link, no, I am sorry but I do not know of something with better performance.

Comment: Looks cool, but I can't afford to pay for licensing right now.